# Need Comparison of Object of same type to know the difference in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, comparison

I need to compare the object to know what properties are changed and what properties are added new.
    Is there any code snippet which will loop through entire object and its properties and alert if any changes exist and continue its process till the end.

Consider i need to compare the gridpanel(object) in extjs before and after show and hide event of its parent panel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, this "smells" like you're on the wrong track here

Comment: Hi Hemlock...1.iam not thinking like that. 2.the problem is. I place the extjs grid in the panel its worked fine, i will hide the panel and show it again many times in some case the grid is not visible, when i view the hidden property its not true . so i need to know which property changes makes this issue...if we can able to write it in a text file we can simple diffmerge it and view the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check if two objects of the same class differ:

```
function differ(a, b) {
  for (var i in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(i) && b.hasOwnProperty(i) && a[i] === b[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

a = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
b = {bar: 2};

alert( differ(a, b) ? "Objects differ" : "Objects are the same" );
```

If that's not what you're after, explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was adding objects to an array. I wanted to be sure, that the same object is not added twice.

I found a helper function for ExtJS which implements a function that compares objects based on the values contained by the object:

https://github.com/nmishra/helpers.js

It then can be used like this:

```
var obj1 = {foo: 'bar'},
    obj2 = {foo: 'bar'},
    equality = Ext.ux.util.Object.compareObject(obj1, obj2);
console.log(equality);
```